# How does \protected deal with arguments? Is it different than \protect?

Tags: beamer, expansion, protected-macro, fragile

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n) `\protect\foo` expands to something like `\noexpand\protect\noexpand\foo` when it gets saved to a macro (e.g. in a context like a beamer frame).  I think `\protected\def` basically just places \protect in front of every instance of the macro.  If not, what does it do?   If so why does `\expandafter` in a protected macro applied to an argument work correctly?

The rest is just provided for clarification.  I'm trying to understand what `\protected` does and felt the example might help explain what I'm asking.

For instance, the command defined below works fine even in beamer frames but if I think about what happens if I replaced `\Tdeg{\zeron{5}}` with `\noexpand\protect\noexpand\Tdeg{\zeron{5}}` wouldn't the result be to expand the argument `\zeron{5}` before it caught by the `\expandafter` in `\Tdeg`?  If so why does this still work (i.e. output A not B) when I run it inside a beamer frame?

```
\def\zeron#1{0^{#1}}
\def\first@pmg@rdmxs(#1#2){#1}
\protected\def\Tdeg#1{\ifthenelse{
           \equal{\string \zeron }{\expandafter\string \first@pmg@rdmxs(#1)}
            {A}
            {B}}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's still the same problem: how can we test this without a full example?

Comment: But I don't want to know what the code does or to fix it.  I want to understand how \protected works with macro arguments. The only point of the code is that I can use \expandafter on an argument in a protected macro and it sometimes seems to delay the expansion even in contexts where protected isn't \relax.

If that isn't clear enough from the post just delete the post as I've failed to communicate utterly as the only point of the code was to illustrate how one might *incorrectly* reason about \protected.

Comment: neither `\protect` not `\protected` deal with arguments at all. as you say if you use `\protect\Tdeg{\zeron{5}}` in an expansion context, the expansion of `\Tdeg` will be suppressed but `\zeron{5}` will expand. But you haven't shown any `\Tdeg` being used in such a context (or any context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\protected` is unrelated to the LaTeX macro `\protect` it sets a flag on a macro similar to `\long` but otherwise has no effect at the point of definition.

so

```
\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\show\foo

\long\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\show\foo

\protected\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\show\foo
```

produces

```
> \foo=macro:
->zzz \textbf {x}.
l.3 \show\foo
             
? 
> \foo=\long macro:
->zzz \textbf {x}.
l.6 \show\foo
             
? 
> \foo=\protected macro:
->zzz \textbf {x}.
l.9 \show\foo
```

However when used in an expansion-only context such as `\edef` or `\write` a `protected` macro acts like `\relax` and does not expand.

So...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\immediate\write20{1: \foo}

\long\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\immediate\write20{2: \foo}


\protected\def\foo{zzz \textbf{x}}
\immediate\write20{3: \foo}


\end{document}
```

Produces

```
1: zzz \protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \def l3backend-pdftex.def{x}\let \futu
relet \@let@token \let \protect \relax \edef cmr{cmr}\edef cmss{cmss}\edef cmtt
{cmtt}\def ##1,b,{}\series@check@toks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,me
c,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},b,}\edef {}\edef b{b}\def ##1,m,{}\series@check@to
ks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,mec,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},m,}\ed
ef {}\edef m{m}\protect \let
```

```
2: zzz \protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \def l3backend-pdftex.def{x}\let \futu
relet \@let@token \let \protect \relax \edef cmr{cmr}\edef cmss{cmss}\edef cmtt
{cmtt}\def ##1,b,{}\series@check@toks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,me
c,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},b,}\edef {}\edef b{b}\def ##1,m,{}\series@check@to
ks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,mec,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},m,}\ed
ef {}\edef m{m}\protect \let
```

```
3: \foo
```

Where you see that `\foo` doesn't fare well in a `\write` (and `\protect` would not help as normally it is `\relax` and only has the special definition within `\typeout`, `\protected@write` and similar latex constructs) but the `\protected` version of `\foo` stays as `\foo` in the `\write`.

Comment: Thanks that clarified my confusion and explained what's going on.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The LaTeX `\protect` mechanism and the e-TeX `\protected` one work differently. A macro defined using `\protected\def` will not expand inside an `\edef` or similar context, but otherwise is exactly the same as one defined using `\def`. In contrast, `\protect` uses a token of variable definition to avoid expansion in some places: this requires 'opt-in' processing (`\protected@edef` or similar) to 'active' this mechanism.